# How to remove pip package after deleting it manually

Tags: python, pip

I deleted a pip package with `rm -rf` command thinking that the package will be removed. Now the package has been deleted but it still shows up in `pip list` and I'm unable to remove it with `pip uninstall` nor can I update with `pip install --upgrade`.

I'd like to remove it completely. Can anyone please tell me how?

**EDIT**

The package is psycopg2.

If I try to uninstall :

```
hammad@hammad-P5QL-E:~$ pip uninstall psycopg2
Can't uninstall 'psycopg2'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

This is the directory in which psycopg2 was located `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`and I `rm -rf` 'd it from the same directory.

TIA

Comment: `easy_install -m pip`

Comment: @PriyankPatel  I want to remove a package from pip! not install pip

Comment: Unfortunately, you'd need to manually create the deleted folders or copy it from a different installation and then try `pip uninstall` you may also try `pip install` the package again and then `pip uninstall`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

packages installed using pip can be uninstalled completely using

```
pip uninstall <package>
```

[refrence link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_uninstall/)

`pip uninstall` is likely to fail if the package is installed using `python setup.py install` as they do not leave behind metadata to determine what files were installed.

packages still show up in `pip list` if their paths(.pth file) still exist in your site-packages or dist-packages folder. You'll need to remove them as well in case you're removing using `rm -rf`

Comment: What about OP's text "I'm unable to remove it with `pip uninstall`"?

Comment: also completely missed the point about "it still shows up in `pip list`"

Comment: Yes there was a `psycopg2-2.4.5.egg-info` in the dist-packages folder. Deleting it completely removed the package.

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to address the question.

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to the `site-packages` directory where pip is installing your packages.
2. You should see the egg file that corresponds to the package you want to uninstall.  Delete the egg file (or, to be on the safe side, move it to a different directory).
3. Do the same with the package files for the package you want to delete (in this case, the `psycopg2` directory).
4. `pip install YOUR-PACKAGE`

Comment: This should be the correct answer, if the person will come with the commands, for noobies things are new and they are exactly looking for the correct commands. Anyways this solution tackled the question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there's a better way to achieve this and I would like to read about it, but a workaround I can think of is this:

1. Install the package on a different machine.
2. Copy the `rm`'ed directory to the original machine (ssh, ftp, whatever).
3. `pip uninstall` the package (should work again then).

But, yes, I'd also love to hear about a decent solution for this situation.

Comment: omg this is literally a workaround! but too bad I don't have an extra machine.

Comment: ① What kind of error do you receive, ② what directory did you `rm`, ③ what package are we talking about?

Comment: You know, we all have machines, and we are here to help ;-)

Comment: Right, didnt think about your machines. Ill edit the question, please look at it.

Comment: Btw, you could also setup a _virtualenv_ and `pip install` that package therein to get an image of the `rm`'ed directory.

Comment: If it helps, python directory is `/usr/local/bin/` and psycopg2 is no longer visible in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` but still showing up in `pip list`

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue while experimenting with my own Python library and what I've found out is that `pip freeze` will show you the library as installed if **your current directory** contains `lib.egg-info` folder. And `pip uninstall <lib>` will give you the same error message.

1. Make sure your current directory doesn't have any `egg-info` folders
2. Check `pip show <lib-name>` to see the details about the location of the library, so you can remove files manually.