# pip displays incorrect version of package

Tags: python, pip

I am not sure if this is a bug, or if I am doing something wrong.
The situation is the following,

```
pip list -o
```

yields a list of outdated python packages along with what is suppose to be the current installed version.
The issue is that I am pretty sure that it is giving me the wrong information on at least some packages as I can verify, as in the example below, that the version of ipython that pip thinks is installed (2.0.0) is not the one that I get when I run ipython from the command prompt (version==2.1.0).

```
kolmogorov:~# pip list -o | head -15
Warning: cannot find svn location for PEAK-Rules==0.5a1.dev-r2707
Warning: cannot find svn location for prioritized-methods==0.2.2dev-20110830
scipy (Current: 0.13.2 Latest: 0.14.0)
plotly (Current: 1.0.30 Latest: 1.0.32)
SOAPpy (Current: 0.12.21 Latest: 0.12.22)
openpyxl (Current: 1.8.6 Latest: 2.0.3)
networkx (Current: 1.8.1 Latest: 1.9)
setuptools (Current: 3.4.1 Latest: 5.1)
brewer2mpl (Current: 1.3.2 Latest: 1.4)
repoze.who (Current: 1.0.19 Latest: 2.2)
pandas (Current: 0.13.1 Latest: 0.14.0)
pygeocoder (Current: 1.2.2 Latest: 1.2.5)
ipython (Current: 2.0.0 Latest: 2.1.0)
tornado (Current: 3.2 Latest: 3.2.2)
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement vboxapi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 235, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 156, in main
    logger.fatal('Exception:\n%s' % format_exc())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 111, in fatal
    self.log(self.FATAL, msg, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 164, in log
    consumer.flush()
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


kolmogorov:~# ipython
Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun  3 2014, 16:16:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

My question is: Is there a way to have pip understand the correct version of the installed python packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way to do this properly is a little bit more involved than what I anticipated, but I have to submit it as the proper answer as it actually resolves the issue.

Suppose the package version that is misunderstood by `pip` is `pandas`.  So that the behavior you observe is that:

```
pip list --outdated
```

says that the version of `pandas` you have installed is `0.14.0`; but when you inquire about the version of `pandas` in say `ipython`:

```
In [1]: import pandas 

In [2]: pandas.__version__
Out[2]: '0.14.1'
```

In order to resolve this:

1. run `pip show pandas`; it should tell you about the location of the distribution, in my case `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
2. redirect to that location `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
3. run `ls -lstrh pandas-0.14.*`; you should see files associated with both your `0.14.1` version and the `0.14.0` one you want to get rid of
4. run `rm -rf pandas-0.14.0*.egg-info pandas-0.14.0*.pth`

That should be it!

```
pip show pandas
```

should now agree with what `pandas.__version__`

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following commands to see where the package is from:

```
which ipython
```

and:

```
pip show ipython
```

You may have two installations: one that was installed with `pip install ipython` and an installation via a separate tool (package manager on Linux or Ports/brew on Mac).

Comment: I am removing the aptitude installed versions.

Comment: super weird:

    kolmogorov:~# pip show ipython
    ---
    Name: ipython
    Version: 2.0.0
    Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requires: 
    kolmogorov:~# pip uninstall ipython
    Can't uninstall 'ipython'. No files were found to uninstall.

Comment: pip is not able to uninstall all packages: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_uninstall.html . It could also be that the metadata file is missing.

Comment: I am not sure this issue is resolved, to be perfectly honest.
I started with pip not knowing the version of ipython I had on the machine.  I am STILL at pip not knowing which version of ipython is on the machine.  I tried removing the possible version installed with aptitude, but I still have a version of ipython (2.1.0), that I now am pretty sure WAS installed with pip, which thinks it should only have version (2.0.0)

Comment: this helped [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306954/how-to-remove-pip-package-after-deleting-it-manually?rq=1]