# Can't uninstall project with no packages

Tags: python, pip

While trying to build an MCVE for another question, I created an `example` directory with one file in it, a `setup.py` with the following contents:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='example',
)
```

and installed it with

```
python3.6 setup.py sdist
python3.6 -m pip install --user dist/example-0.0.0.tar.gz
```

No actual packages or modules, but *something* got installed:

```
redacted:~/example> python3.6 -m pip list | grep example
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
example (0.0.0)
```

Now I can't uninstall it:

```
redacted:~/example> python3.6 -m pip uninstall example
Can't uninstall 'example'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

[Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21307272) suggest there might be a `.pth` file I have to remove from my `site-packages` directory, but I don't see any:

```
redacted:~/example> find ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ -name '*.pth'
redacted:~/example>
```

What did I just do to my system, and how can I undo it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps shown in the question *will* actually create and install a real package. It won't create any importable files, but it will create metadata in a site-packages directory. Exactly where it has installed depends on your [USER_SITE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) configuration, which you can check with `python3.6 -m site`, but it's probably going to be at `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/example-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info`.

Path files (.pth) are unrelated.

The reason it can't uninstall, saying:

> Can't uninstall 'example'. No files were found to uninstall.

is because the build command executed earlier will have created an `example.egg-info` in the current directory, and using `python3.6 -m pip` [means the empty-string is in `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m). So, the current directory is also considered a package location. Since the current working directory, at `sys.path[0]`, is before the user site the `example.egg-info` metadata will be found here instead of in site-packages.

The command `python3.6 -m pip uninstall` also finds this build artifact first, for the same reasons, and does not find the metadata from site-packages which has a record of the files that should be removed during an uninstall. To correctly uninstall this package you could:

```
rm -rf example.egg-info   # first prevent pip from getting confused by the temporary build artifact in cwd
python3.6 -m pip uninstall example  # uninstall it from the user site
```

Or, you could change directory before uninstalling, so that pip finds the package metadata for `example` in the user site instead of in the working directory.

***Note 1:** These workarounds are not required for [pip >= 20.1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2020-04-21). Since April 2020, using `python -m pip` now ejects the cwd from `sys.path` and it will uninstall successfully from the user site in the first place without getting confused ([#7731](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7731))*

***Note 2:** some details are slightly different if this python3.6 environment has a wheel installation in it - in this case the install command will first create a wheel file from the sdist, and then install the wheel, which will result in an `example-0.0.0.dist-info` subdirectory for the metadata instead of an egg-info subdirectory, but the important details are the same whether you have an .egg-info or .dist-info style install in the user site. It is not possible to determine from the details in the question whether the python3.6 environment had a wheel installation available.*

Answer (score -3):

Since you didn't specify any files, there was nothing to be installed. So you can't uninstall anything either.

Comment: It did *something*. `python3.6 -m pip list` shows an entry for `example (0.0.0)`, saying it was installed.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, but pip doesn't find any files, it's probably only in some pip manifest