# Pip permission denied on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

For some reasons, I was installing python packages using sudo pip for python3.6 back in my Ubuntu 18.04. I recently upgraded ubuntu version to 20.04 which comes with python3.8 which I want to continue with. Therefore, now, my system has three python versions - 2.7, 3.6, 3.8.

```
$ pip -V
pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)

$ pip3 -V
pip 20.3.4 from /home/dell/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ python -V
2.7.18

$ python3 -V 
Python 3.8.10
```

But whenever I install python packages using pip3, it shows the following error -

```
$ pip3 install numpy
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.4.1 requires numpy~=1.19.2, but you have numpy 1.22.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed numpy-1.22.0
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-target-x7bedgtq/lib/python/numpy-1.22.0.dist-info' -> '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy-1.22.0.dist-info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 453, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 510, in _handle_target_dir
    shutil.move(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 807, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, copy_function=copy_function,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 557, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 458, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy-1.22.0.dist-info'
```

It is somehow pointing to python3.6 numpy package which I installed using sudo pip. How can I solve this? Is there anyway that python3.6 packages can be unblocked from sudo access?

Or will it be fine to uninstall all the packages in '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/'?

EDIT for @psarka comment,

```
$ sudo python3.6 -m pip uninstall numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, as you are doing things the wrong way, and facing the direct consequences of doing things the wrong way. So stop, and use `venv`! :)

```py
cd my_project
python3.8 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install whatever
```

If you don't have python3.8-venv, install it:

```
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
```

Comment: I definitely must have messed up python things a lot by not using venv previously. But I tried with venv too just the same way you mentioned, It is the same error. Any other solutions?

Comment: Hmm, try removing the offending package. First without sudo (you should get the same access denied error), then with sudo: `sudo python3.6 -m pip uninstall numpy`.

Comment: please look at my edit... it now throws another error. I have tried `sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils`... still the same error.

Comment: No use trying to slog through this, just do clean reinstall of your OS.

Comment: I recommend to try pipenv which in my opinion makes handling virtual environments very easy and less error prone https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: @pydvlpr I used it as well after the problem started. But it seems it is too late. It is still showing the same permission error.

Comment: Have a look at this threat. It gives information about removing pip packages and doing some troubleshooting if things got weird. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306954/how-to-remove-pip-package-after-deleting-it-manually And here a some more infos about package locations https://servicedesk.mtu.edu/TDClient/1801/Portal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=66715